# time format change in shell

Tags: linux, shell, date

In my log file the time format is 2014-10-10    `HH:MM:SS:sss`.
I am reading the time and date from the file and converting it into seconds for further processing. But it's giving error the date is invalid. May be it's because time is not in ..SS.sss format.

```
while read line;
do
 d1=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f2);
case "$line" in \s*) continue ;; esac
t1=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f3);
d1t1="${d1} ${t1}";
echo "$d1t1";
ds1=$(date -d"$d1t1" "+%s");
echo "$ds1";
done < error.log
```

I want to replace ":" by "." which is the way to solve the problem?

Comment: Please show error log file some sample content.

Comment: ,2014-04-08,10:45:06:247,aa,bb,cc,dd .....

Comment: Please show at least a *complete* line... It's not clear if the date field and time field for ma single date specification, because they are separated by a comma, which is the separator for all fields...

Comment: it's csv file 1st is blank. second is date and third is time . after that there are 17 fields which are comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to simply replace the milliseconds separator in your log file?

```
perl -p -i -e 's/:(\d{3}),/.\1/g' error.log
```

A ':' separator for milliseconds *is wrong*, and date command will complain aboult it. With a '.' separator date command will succeed.

**UPDATE:**
The command is a "perl inliner": it applies text changes to a file ("error.log", in this case), globally (for every row).
The change command here is a [regular expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) substitution: `s/:(\d{3}),/.\1/g`, which means: "*substitute every colon followed by exaclty 3 digits and a comma with a dot and the digits*".

Comment: above command removed the comma too after the miliseconds. It's now ,2014-04-08,10:45:06:247aa,bb,cc,dd

Comment: can you explain me the meaning of your command ,so that I can modify it.